# Нахождение позиции символа в строке

Tags: c++

Есть строка, в ней нужно найти символ `'='` и записать его позицию в переменную. Какие существуют решения?

Comment: Если вы таким образом собираетесь парсить что-нибудь, возможно, вы идёте неправильным путём.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы найти элемент в строке используется метод [`std::string:find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), он вернет позицию первого вхождения. Если символ или подстрока не входят в исходную строку, вернет [`std::string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos):

```
std::string equation = "1 + 2 = 4";
std::cout << equation.find('=') << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы не сообщили, в объекте какого типа у вас хранится строка.

Ниже показана демонстрационная программа, которая осуществляет поиск символа в символьном массиве `s1` и в объекте с именем `s2` класса `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char s1[] = "2 * 2 = 4";
    std::string s2( s1 );
    char c = '=';

    char *p = std::strchr( s1, c );

    if ( p != nullptr ) 
    {        
        std::cout << "Character " << c << " found at position " << p - s1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The rest of the string is \"" << p << "\"" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string::size_type n = s2.find( c );

    if ( n != std::string::npos ) 
    {        
        std::cout << "Character " << c << " found at position " << n << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The rest of the string is \"" << s2.substr( n ) << "\"" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль выглядит следующим образом:

```
Character '=' found at position 6
The rest of the string is "= 4"
Character '=' found at position 6
The rest of the string is "= 4"
```