# Как узнать индекс элементав массиве char c++ (Arduino)

Tags: c++, arduino

У меня есть массив данных char

```
char chrs[] = "Привет";
```

Мне нужно найти индекс буквы в этом массиве например:

```
findIndex(chrs, 'П') // должно возвращать 0 
findIndex(chrs, 'в') // должно возвращать 3
```

Как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: [Возможный дубликат вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/434384/508294)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Нахождение позиции символа в строке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/434384/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: insolor, rusgeli, не является дубликатом, так как Arduino не поддерживает stl.

Comment: У ардуиновского класса String есть метод IndexOf https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/strings/StringIndexOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int findIndex (char* str, char ltr) 
 {
    char* p = str;
    while (*p) {
       if (*p == ltr)
          return (int) p - (int) str;
       ++p;
    }
    return -1; // Если буквы в строке нет, вернуть -1.
 }
```